# Symfony2 Assetic CSS rewriting breaks on url(data:image...)

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I faced a problem with Assetic's CSS rewrite. It works fine in the sense it makes the URLs correct, however, it also ruins `data:image` URLs like this:

```
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWw...');
```

into:

```
background: url('../../bundles/proj/css/data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWw...');
```

Is there a workaround or a fix to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a pull request for this fix: https://github.com/srosato/assetic/commit/1504cc79588acf418ab5d28320174ef15e603f96